# Submit a form with multiple possible actions Laravel

Tags: laravel, forms

I am using Laravel framework, where I have a form, which has a list of profiles displayed (using Profile Model). All these profiles are bound with a single checkbox array. There is a button at the top that when clicked, deletes the selected profiles (The action used here is ProfileController@deleteProfile). Also each profile has a button next to it, which when clicked, is supposed to go to ProfileController@editProfile action, but I am not sure where to specify this different action in the form. Is there a way to trigger a different action when Edit button is clicked?

```
@if(count($profiles) > 0) 

{!! Form::open(['action' => ['AdminController@deleteProfile'], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
{{  Form::submit('Delete Selected Profiles', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) }}  
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Select</th>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($profiles as $profile)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ $profile->id }}</th>

                <td>   
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedProfiles[]" value="{{ $profile->id }}" />                           
                </td>
                <td>{{ $profile->title }}</td>
                <td>
                    {{  Form::hidden('id', $profile->id) }}    
                    {{  Form::submit('Edit', ['class' => 'btn btn-secondary']) }}                                  
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{!! Form::close() !!}

@endif
```

Another approach I tried was to create a generalized action ProfileModify where I would pass an extra variable to specify the kind of action I wanted to implement, 'Edit' or 'Delete' but I can't find a way to pass the Hidden input conditionally to send "Edit" or "Delete" when we click 2 separate buttons.

Can someone suggest how to approach this issue, and if this is actually possible, and if not, a better possible alternative to tackle this situation?

Comment: Does `ProfileController@editProfile` display the edit form for a profile?

Comment: Yes, it would display the edit form for the profile with the profile details mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a form submit to link to the edit page of the profile, just use an `a` tag.

If you have named routes:

```php
{{ link_to_route('profile.edit', 'Edit', ['id' => $profile->id]) }}
```

For actions:

```php
{{ link_to_action('ProfileController@editProfile', 'Edit', ['id' => $profile->id]) }}
```

[Docs](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/docs/blob/5.6/html.md#generating-urls)

Comment: If the last parameter is the array of all parameters to be passed to the action editProfile, what does the 2nd parameter 'Edit' mean? I checked the Docs and there it says $title=null, which title is it referring to?

Comment: It is referring to the the text in the a tag: `<a>Edit</a>`

Comment: Also, it's passing the information to the action through the URL, is there a way to avoid it and pass it through POST without having to submit a form?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid passing it through the URL? It should be something like `/profile/1/edit`. If you want use `POST` then you need a form for it, but I don't see a reason why you would want that.